# InvalidRegex: pattern not supported in my xsd

Tags: java, regex, eclipse, jaxb

I'm writing an xsd, from which i will need to build jaxb classes.

I can't validate for this regex:

```
<element name="myValue" maxOccurs="1"
            minOccurs="0">
            <simpleType>
                <restriction base="time">
                    <pattern
                        value="^(?:2[0-3]|[01][0-9]):[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]$">
                    </pattern>
                </restriction>
            </simpleType>
        </element>
```

It gaves me:

> InvalidRegex: Pattern value '^(?:2[0-3]|[01][0-9]):[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]$' is not a valid regular expression. The reported error was: 'This expression is not supported in the current option setting.'.

But I really don't have a clue on how to adjust it.
I've made massive researches here and there and tried possible attempts to obtain a "hh24:mm:ss" pattern date leading zeros mandatory but with no luck.

I prefer not to chang something in the Eclipse preferences to amend, i would like to get a fully "international" solution.

thanks f your cooperation

Comment: Eclipse has nothing to do with your invalid regex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

^(2[0-3]|[01][0-9]):[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]$

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! It would be helpful if you included a link to a website that tests this regex pattern, and/or included a description of how this works.

Comment: Try https://regex101.com/
The hour part accepts one of two things:
  - 20, 21, 22 or 23.  (the part of the expression to the left of the | )
  - 00 to 19  ( the [01][09] part )